# Write heading in document once per tag with handlebars helpers/for loops

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an array of objects that each have a property 'tag' with different names. I'm using handlebars to loop through the set of questions and display the question title and the data for each question. Each are in order depending on what tag they have and I'd like to have a heading that displays the tag property when it is unique.

I have something like:

```
var questions = [
  {
    title: 'This is the first question',
    tag: 'FirstTag'
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the second question',
    tag: 'FirstTag'
  },{
    title: 'This is the third question',
    tag: 'SecondTag'
  }]
```

And I'm looping through them in the index like this, wanted to add a handlebars helper like this:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{display_tag}}
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

I wanted to try something like, find if the element exists with the id, if it doesn't: make it. If it does, don't make it. But the code I've written here just makes the tag appear before every question.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('display_tag', function() {
  if ($('#' + this.tag).length < 1) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    "<a id='" + this.tag + "'><h3>" + this.tag + "</h3></a>"
   );
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very similar using plain Handlebars (no Ember.js):

```
var tags = [];
questions.forEach(function(question) {
    if (tags.indexOf(question.tag) >= 0) {
        question.tagAlreadyUsed = true;
    } else {
        tags.push(question.tag);
        question.tagAlreadyUsed = false;
    }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each this}}
    {{#unless tagAlreadyUsed}}
        <a id="{{tag}}"><h3>tag</h3></a>
    {{/unless}}
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

---

You can't use jQuery in the helper because your template isn't actually in the DOM yet. Your if condition will always be true. There's two ways that I would accomplish this:

1. Before you render the data in the template, go over the data and insert the properties you need. For instance, you could loop through your questions and insert a `tagAlreadyUsed` property that you could then use in your template to toggle the display of the tag.
2. You could write a handlebars helper that renders the entire list, which would allow you to keep track of state between the items.

I would recommend the first. Perhaps something like this?

Controller:

```
taggedQuestions: function() {
    var tags = new Em.Set();

    var questions = this.get('questions').map(function(question) {
        if (tags.contains(question.tag)) {
            question.tagAlreadyUsed = true;
        } else {
            tags.addObject(tag);
            question.tagAlreadyUsed = false;
        }

        return question;
    });

    return questions;
}.property('questions.@each.tag')
```

Template:

```
{{#each taggedQuestions}}
    {{#unless tagAlreadyUsed}}
        <a {{bind-attr id=tag}}><h3>tag</h3></a>
    {{/unless}}
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was my fault because of the ember.js tag used here but this isn't actually an ember project. I'm just using handlebars.
What might this look like without the use of a controller?

Comment: It's the same solution, you just perform your mapping logic elsewhere. See my updated answer.